# Unity имена параметров в реестре

Tags: unity3d

При сохранении параметров в реестр юнити добавляет к имени параметра некоторые символы, например вот так:

```
Screenmanager Resolution Height_h2627697771
Screenmanager Resolution Width_h182942802
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за символы, как они формируются и зачем?

Необходимо программно менять эти параметры, но пока единственный способ, это проверка на маску 'ParamName_*'

Comment: а с какой целью вы их менять хотите? Может быть существует иной способ, без таких извращений, как манимуляция реестром)

Comment: С целью управления появлением окна юнити в нужном мне месте и с нужным размером. Окно криво реагирует на программный ресайз, через winapi, поэтому так.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/13523/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-position-of-a-standalone.html вот этот ответ с форума Unity не поможет? Он использует стороннюю dll для поиска окна и задания нужных параметров.

Comment: @M.Green, спасибо за помощь, но я знаю этот способ и он работает не всегда, кроме того, способ не полный, т.к. еще можно рулить стилями окна и убирать бордеры на лету)

Comment: @M.Green мне просто интересно, чуть менее чем все ВР приложения сейчас клепают на юнити и никто не знает что и зачем это чудовище пишет в реестр? в мануалах я ничего не нашел, смотреть исходники мне (пока) лень, но чувствую придется)

Comment: Вообще на этом сайте принято прикреплять код к вопросу, как и что вы записываете в реестр - большой вопрос :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по хэшу на конце, вы используете PlayerPrefs, Unity "под капотом" дописывает к концу названия ключа его хэш [по алгоритму djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html). Делается это только ради защиты от коллизий имен ключей в регистре.

Проверяется это все очень просто:

```
public static string UnityRegistryHash(string name) {
    uint hash = 5381;
    foreach (char c in name)
        hash = hash * 33 ^ c;
    return name + "_h" + hash;
}

[MenuItem("Debug/Registry key hash test")]
public static void RegistryKeyHashTest() {
    string var1 = "Screenmanager Resolution Height";
    string var2 = "Screenmanager Resolution Width";

    Debug.Log(UnityRegistryHash(var1));
    Debug.Log(UnityRegistryHash(var2));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если вы используете PlayerPrefs и для чтения и для записи - то такой проблемы быть не должно. Зачем вы вообще ищете среди реестра нужные вам данные, если PlayerPrefs делает это за вас? Все, что требуется от вас - где-то хранить оригинальный ключ, без `_hXXXXXXXXXX` - это забота Unity.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Реестр надо менять из другой программы, написанной на pure winapi)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, тогда лучше и в Unity писать в регистр через winapi. Мешать 2 этих способа - не очень хорошая идея. Но, с другой стороны, вы можете сами высчитывать хэш по djb2 в другой программе.